# Polymorphic generics

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, generics, polymorphism

I have a generic class `Command(Of T)`

Command is defined (in part) as:

```
Public Class Command(Of T As BaseType)
    Inherits Command
    Public Property Condition As Func(Of T, Boolean)
End Class
```

I want to create a list of all commands, then when I'm handed an object `A`, pull out all commands with the same generic type as my `A` for which a call to `Condition(A)` returns true

I can do

```
Dim B As List(Of BaseType)
B.Add(New DerivedType)
```

But

```
Dim C As New List(Of Command(Of BaseType))
C.Add(New Command(Of DerivedType))
```

Throws a conversion error.

I can make `Command` inherit from a non-generic object (let's call it `CommandBase`...)

```
Dim C As New List(Of CommandBase)
C.Add(New Command(Of DerivedType))
```

Which works but now I can't get back to the type-specific reference. This gets the right command objects:

```
Dim CommandsOfTypeA = B.Where(function(x) x.GetType.GetGenericArguments(0).FullName = A.GetType.FullName)
```

But I can't now see how to do...

```
Dim MatchingCommands = CommandsOfTypeA.Where(function(x) c.Condition(A))
```

As CommandsOfTypeA is a `List(Of Command)` not `List(Of Command(Of DerivedType))`

What am I missing?

Comment: @MattBall Thanks, I'm obviously a little tired

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while an an instance of `DerivedType` is an instance of `BaseType`, that doesn't necessarily mean that an instance of `Command(Of DerivedType)` is an instance of `Command(Of BaseType)`.  By default, type hierarchies are not considered for generic type parameters.

In programming language theory, the feature that enables this is called [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

.net 4.0 does have some support for this, although it can only be applied to interfaces, not classes.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx) is some documentation on the subject.

Basically, it looks like this:

```
Interface ICovariant(Of Out R)
    Function GetSomething() As R
    ' The following statement generates a compiler error. 
    ' Sub SetSomething(ByVal sampleArg As R) 
End Interface
```

This only works (as illustrated) when your generic type is only used as method inputs, never outputs, or `ref` or `output` parameters.

Comment: I had assumed that since Command is `Command(Of T As BaseType)` then every `Command(Of Anything)` _has_ to be a ``Command(Of BaseType)` but as you say, clearly it's not being checked. Is this the right appraoch to take or is there a better way to wire this up and still be strongly typed?

Comment: Hmmm ok, I don't think that's going to work for me as I need my condition lambda to be based on `T`

Comment: @Basic:  The `IEnumerable(of T)` interface is generic, so where `List(Of Command(Of BaseType))` doesn't work, you may be able to get what you need by declaring your variable as `IEnumerable(Of Command(Of BaseType))` instead.